# why "simple message" classes are not thread safe?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why does all of the industrial simple message package classes has a warning: THIS CLASS IS NOT THREAD-SAFE?
What makes them not thread safe?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277788/why-%22simple-message%22-classes-are-not-thread-safe?/) by [ManMan88](https://answers.ros.org/users/28824/manman88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2017-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What makes them not thread safe?

The message classes are (de)serialising C-structs from/to a byte buffer.

Buffer accesses are not thread safe, as they don't lock any of the resources that they use.

In addition to that reading and writing bytes from/to the network socket file descriptor is not guarded either.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3